# Web Google Analytics Implementation

Tags: asp.net, mobile, web, google-analytics

I am implementing  Google Analytics on my mobile web application, and I need to know
why are there two urls used:

https://ssl.google-analytics.com

http://www.google-analytics.com

Do I need them both? (I have a problem using https in this application).

10X!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on Analytics Help:

> The Google Analytics tracking code is now the same for both secure and non-secure websites. The new tracking code detects the protocol of the page being tracked and matches the security of your web page automatically. Pages with URLs beginning with http:// will download the non-secure version at http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js and pages with URLs beginning with https:// will load the secure version at https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js. No modification of the tracking code on secure pages is required.